# copy images from a txt list to a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have more than 15000 image files in a single folder. I need to find files that I have in a .txt file, then copy them to a different folder.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in (C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\list3.txt) do (
    for /r "C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Rala Upload\Rala Images 2" %b in ("%a*") do (
        copy "%~Fb" C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\DestinationFolder
    )
)
```

this runs but no images end up in the destination folder could anyone save my hair line I am a complete novice at this cmd stuff and batch files so please excuse being a numpty

Comment: You know, within batch scripts, the `for` loop variables need double percents.  `for /f "delims=" %%a in...` and so forth.  Can you post a few lines of the contents of your .txt file?

Comment: B101F_Fuchsia_FT 
BA407_Black_FT 
BA407_DarkGrey_FT 
BA407_Navy_FT 
BA802_RawBlue_FT 
BA804_DeepBlueDenim_FT 
BA851_Black_FT                                                                                          this is a few lines  from my txt file these are on separate lines is the %% meant on all that I have

Comment: I get %% was unexpected at this time when I place the double %%

Comment: He means when you're using the variable. You should be using `%%a` instead of `%a` (and `%%b` instead of `%b`).

Comment: Why do you need a nested `for` loop?

Comment: Hi Marc                                                                                                           Sorry I'm lost now as I say I am really new to this and just staring out I have just done this with trial and error so I am sorry I don't know what a nested loop is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
@echo off
REM setup some variables
set file_list=C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\list3.txt
set target_dir=C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\DestinationFolder

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%file_list%) do (
   REM remove the ECHO here if output looks good
   echo copy "C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Rala Upload\Rala Images 2\%%i" %target_dir%
)
echo.
echo Done!
```

Run that, and inspect the output.  If the output looks good, remove the `echo` on the copy line, which will activate the script for real.  On small scripts like this, `echo`ing the output first is a safer way to debug before you attempt the real thing.

Comment: ive run in a batch file it runs but nothing appears in the destination folder when run in cmd prompt I get       %%i was unexpected at this time below the  for /f "tokens=*" %%i (%file_list%)

Comment: As another commenter said, you use `%%i` in batch files, and `%i` on the command line.  Paste my code above into a file, save it as `copybat.bat`, and run that at the command line.  If you don't see anything, especially the "Done" output, then there's a bigger problem with your environment.  Oh, and as @Stephan mentions, YOU NEED TO REMOVE THE ECHO if you want this to actually copy files. I provided the inert version so you could inspect it before running it for real (as my notes say).

Comment: for security reasons, we tend to "unarm" potentionally dangerous commands,by `echo` to Show them on Screen without executing them. If the Output is fine, remove the `echo` in front of `copy`

Comment: Right i did that on cmd prompt and got a scrolling black box then got the done at the end i then removed the echo and got the same but still nothing in the destination folder i saved it as a batch file clicked and got a very quick box appear then gone any ideas guys as i am now just following and trying to learn as we go :-)

Comment: the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.        is the msg below each file it trys but the names are correct ahhhhhh! now I'm burning out

Comment: Put the `echo` back in.  Reduce your file list to ONE filename.  Run the script.  copy/paste the output line (e.g. `copy somefile.jpg c:\destinationdir`) directly back onto the command line and it should run if the syntax is correct. If the syntax fails, then it's possible your file or directory don't exist.  I can't answer that for you.